# Selenium more than one baseUrl per test class

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-rc

I am writing selenium scripts on a complex web based application.

To use a useraccount I need to register first using one URL and then approve the account in the admin console on another URL.

The problem is that there is another baseURL for registration and admin console and I need that in one unittest.

But when I use setBaseUrl in my tests it's ignored and the old baseURL is used. I even called start() after that, but no change...

Is there a trick that I am not aware of? I'm playing around and debug for quite some time on this problem, but the decoupled (test <-> RCServer) selenium tests are not making it easier to step through... ;-)

Comment: I always thought unit tests where done on your model layer, not your view layer. Is there a special reason why you are doing unit tests on the view layer?

Also a unit test is designed to test one unit (method), not a series of methods

Comment: the view layer tests are necessary because we use these scripts to ensure the basic functionality of the product after we have build a new version. Doing these tasks by hand takes more than an hour and using selenium lets us keep that down to ~5 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this selenium-rc, I assume you use rc.

Just use two separate selenium instances in the test client. There is no reason why you should have only one selenium instance within one class. That is even cleaner in my opinion since you are talking to two different user interfaces.

On the server side, you still need only one. The server will happily launch two browser instances if requested to do so using two client instances.

Moritz

edit: Just to add this, a now selenium instance can be created anytime with

```
Selenium s = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", 
            "http://your-target-url");
```

Assuming the selenium server is on localhost port 4444.

Comment: very interesting idea. I'll try that on Monday

Answer (score 1):

OK Selenium does not seems to be build for this kind of workflow.

I have split the test class in three test classes.

1. Basic Registration using first baseURL
2. Approval using seconf baseURL
3. Simple tasks using first baseURL again

That's not as clean as having the stuff contained in one testcase because it belongs together from a business perspective. But at least it works and I don't have to hack selenium for it.